# How to trigger ajax request on typing @ multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have below given ajax code for mentions suggestion which triggers a ajax request on typing @. This suggests mentions for typed keyword. But this has a problem. if one mention is selected from suggestions it does not allow to search for more suggestions. It keeps on showing results for first mention keywords. Kindly help.

```
var start=/@/ig;
var word=/@(\w+)/ig;

$("#contentbox").live("keyup",function() 
                      {
  var content=$(this).text();
  var go= content.match(start);
  var name= content.match(word);
  var dataString = 'searchword='+ name;

  if(go.length>0)
  {
    $("#msgbox").slideDown('show');
    $("#display").slideUp('show');
    $("#msgbox").html("Type the name of someone or something...");
    if(name.length>0)
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "boxsearch.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
          $("#msgbox").hide();
          $("#display").html(html).show();
        }
      });

    }
  }
  return false();
});

$(".addname").live("click",function() 
                   {
  var username=$(this).attr('title');
  var old=$("#contentbox").html();
  var content=old.replace(word,""); 
  $("#contentbox").html(content);
  var E="@"+username+"";
  $("#contentbox").append(E);
  $("#display").hide();
  $("#msgbox").hide();
  $("#contentbox").focus();
});
```

Comment: Given your use of `$.live`, I assume you're using a very old version of jQuery? It might be worth adding that to your question, to make sure any answers take that into consideration.